# When ASUTIME LIMIT is met for DB2 stored procedures, will the process ROLLBACK or COMMIT?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, limit, commit

Can't find any answers on the net, has anyone tried this? 
My stored proc processes deletion of tokens found across multiple tables and it is set to run for a specified number of "cpu service units" by using the ASUTIME LIMIT *integer* stored proc definition/characteristic. When this limit is met, will the stored proc commit or rollback the statements executed for the current token?

Thanks.

Comment: not much DB2 activity on this site, only 112 questions ever include "db2" as a tag

Comment: oh gosh yeah.. trial by fire for me now.

Answer (score 1):

thanks.. anyway, a co worker of mine says that:

"With ASUTIME, we are controlling the number of CPU units that the stored procedure will use in its lifetime. If the stored procedure will use more service units than is allowed, the stored procedure will cancel. This means that as long as the app stays within its bounds, the SP will go on.

It can happen that another application, like a report run, will be kicked off while the stored procedure is running. There is no guarantee that the SP will stop at this point, or any point thereafter, because so long as both apps stay within their allowed range, the SP will not terminate. This may not be the intended behavior - most SPs of this nature are run on off days (i.e. Sunday) so that they will not interfere or competewith higher priority jobs during the regular day. In short, they are meant to end, and not to co-run with other jobs.

ASUTIME is designed for runaway stored procedures, not as a tight control on looping within a procedure. WLM priorities and service goals should used be for this, not ASUTIME.

There may not be significant savings  with using ASUTIME, since the stored procedure would also have to check against system resources and the RLST tables."

Posting because it might be helpful to someone else.